# OpenLayers 3 zoom to mouse location pulls off to the left in SharePoint

Tags: openlayers, zoom, sharepoint

I am currently creating a web application using OpenLayers 3 that aims to be embedded into SharePoint using the Script Editor tool.

For the purpose of this question assume I am just using a basic map that brings in OSM data. This works fine in a standalone html file and zooms to the correct location.

However, the issue I am having is that when you zoom in (using the buttons, mouse wheel or holding the shift key and drawing a box) it pulls off to the left when it is embedded into SharePoint.

I am guessing this has something to do with a style or some function in SharePoint rather than something with Openlayers but I thought i'd ask on here to see if anyone else has had a similar issue. The interesting thing is that after setting the map to full screen and then minimizing again, all the zoom functions work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed- Just need to set the maximum pixel width for the web part. It appears that when it tries to adjust widths on the fly, this affects the zooming functions.